# Dynamic array C++, trouble with new Obj[size] creating only 1 Object pointer, not array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I will try to make this direct. And no, I can't use a vector. I have an existing array declared like so in hpp:

```
Item *itemList[4];
```

Then, I need to later create a new size of the array of Object pointers.
Here was my resize array function. It does not work because after the set of slot 1, it runs out of slots. This is because Visual Studio sees **tempList as a singular pointer to a singular Object. What am I missing?:

```
void List::resizeList(int newSiz) {
Item **tempList = new Item *[newSiz];

//Setup tempList
for (int arraySlot = 0; arraySlot < newSiz; ++arraySlot)
    tempList[arraySlot] = NULL;     

//Copy List 
for (int listSlot = 0; listSlot < numArraySlots; listSlot++) {              
    tempList[listSlot] = itemList[listSlot];        
}

delete [] itemList; //Delete Original List
*itemList = *tempList; //Set new itemList
}
```

Adding this screenshot so you can see that Visual Studio thinks that tempList is just a **pointer to a singular Item Object Pointer**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHs7I.png)

```
#ifndef LIST_HPP
#define LIST_HPP

#include "Item.hpp"

class List
{
private:        
    Item *itemList[4]; //Array of 4 Item Object Pointers    
    int numItemsOnList; //Track number of Items on List
    int numArraySlots; //Track Array Slots available for comparison on addToList
public:
    List(); //Default 4 Objects
    void addToList(string nam, string uni, int numBuy, double uniPrice); 
    void delFromList(string itemName); //Using Name for Lookup  
    void resizeList(int newSize); //Resize new array
    void printList(); //Print current List
    double calcTotalPrice(); //Calculate Total Price of items on list
    bool itemExists(string);
};

#endif
```

Comment: The way to create a new dynamic array is to use ``std::vector``. Why are you not using it?

Comment: `itemList2[0] = itemList[0]`, *itemList2* is an **array of Item objects**. *itemList* is an **array of pointers** to Item object.

Comment: Thanks, but did you not read my comment? I cannot use vector. We are not talking about industry standards or best practice here. I need the proper way to do this if this method had to be used.

Comment: Yes thank you. However, my resizeList uses **tempList and newItem*[size]. What is the proper way to create a Dynamic array of pointers to Objects that will mesh with Item *itemList[4]?

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem on my pc. Are you sure `itemList` elements are initialized before you use them? One more thing `delete [] itemList;` you don't need to use `delete` here because this array was not created with `new` operator.

Comment: @bkVnet, Thank you so much! So I should create the new **tempList instead of setting to NULL? Sorry I am not sure how to add in comments as code.

    for (int arraySlot = 0; arraySlot < newSiz; ++arraySlot)tempList[arraySlot] = new Item();

Comment: Its not clear what is not working for you, but i don't think that is the problem since you are creating an array of pointer to Item object there. Try to make sure the contents of `itemList` are valid.You should probable use a debugger and run you code line by line. And what is `numArraySlots` in your second loop?

Comment: why you cannot use a `std::vector` ? c-style arrays can be converted easily to/from vectors, thus even when depending on some c-stylish api I would use vectors. If you are not allowed to use them because it is homework, then it is different of course, however even then I would use vectors :P

Comment: @bkVnet I added a screenshot to my original post. Please take a look. This is what Visual Studio sees tempList as. Whenever I iterate over tempList[arraySlot] it just sets the Item data members of a single item. It does not see a whole array there at all. numArraySlots is a data member that is the size of 4 by default. It is currently int 4. Also, I removed delete as suggested.

Comment: @tobi303 No I cannot use vector otherwise I totally would... This is for a class and this is the last thing I am stuck on after 20 hours of coding.

Comment: I still don't think that is the problem though. its is just showing you the first element that is pointed to by the first pointer in the array. You can set a break point after you initialize the dynamic array, and use the watch window to see the values of each element pointed to by the pointers like `tempList[1]`,`tempList[2]`,etc.. or just use a for loop to display the contents of the elements pointed to by those pointers.

Comment: @bkVnet Ok I will try that. In addition, I have included the List.hpp to show you what all of it is. Item *itemList[4] always works great when adding items. It makes 4 of them and then explodes on resize function.

Comment: BTW try to look carefully at the logic of `resizeList` is trying to accomplish here because the last two statements doesn't make that much sense to me(if it doesn't cause a run time error).

Comment: @bkVnet Yes delete [] itemList was removed since itemList was not dynamically created as new, it was already declared at compile. The very last statement was supposed to copy the tempList over the top of the original data member itemList. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itemList` is statically created array and you can't resize it at run time. what you may want to do is make it a double pointer `Item** itemList`, set its initial size at the constructor of your class using `new`, resize it, and delete its at the `destructor` of the class when the class is destroyed.

Try this:

```
List::List()
{
    itemList=new Item*[4];//allocate its initial size in the constructor
}

List::~List()
{
    delete[] itemList;//release the memory at the destructor
}

void List::resizeList(int newSiz) {
  Item **tempList = new Item *[newSiz];

  //Setup tempList
  for (int arraySlot = 0; arraySlot < newSiz; ++arraySlot)
       tempList[arraySlot] = NULL;     

  //Copy List 
  for (int listSlot = 0; listSlot < numArraySlots; listSlot++)                         
       tempList[listSlot] = itemList[listSlot];        

   delete [] itemList; //Delete Original List
   itemList = tempList; //Set new itemList
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: THANK YOU! That got it. I guess there is some trouble when an array previously declared tries to turn into a dynamic array...